# Why use characters like &quot over ""?

Tags: html

I was wondering why we should use $quot or &ldquot over regular string representations of those characters? What are these characters called and why would we use them anything else in an html file?

I would google this myself but I don't even know what these characters are? Is it Unicode? ASCII?

Is it faster to represent quotes and ellipsis this way?

Comment: May be you'll find it **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25916943/2065039)**

Answer (score 1):

It may have to do with encoding. If you use &quot; etc, you leave it up to the browser and/or the operating system on how to display it. It should work with all encodings.

If you use an actual character, you need to specify the encoding (e.g., utf-8), in the document's meta tag. I prefer to do everything in utf-8 and use real characters as opposed to the html entity equivalents, and I believe that is the W3C recommendation these days (though don't quote me on it).

Answer (score 1):

> why we should use $quot or &ldquot over regular string representations

It's `&quot;` and you would use it only in attribute values delimited by `"` characters because a literal `"` would end the attribute value.

> why we should use &ldquot over regular string representations

It is `&ldquot;` and you would use it either because:

- You had no convenient way to type the literal character
- You were using a character encoding which didn't include the character

The latter shouldn't be a problem this century because we have had good support for UTF-8 for ages.